Is the real and imaginary part of the Dirichlet eta function invertible when viewed as single variable function?
If we examine $\Re(\eta(\alpha + \beta i))$ as a function of $\alpha$ or only $\beta$ is $\eta$ invertible? That is, if we define that map $J:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as
\begin{equation}\label{Eq3}
J(\alpha)=  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{\alpha}}\cos(\beta\ln(n))}
\end{equation}
for any $\beta\in \mathbb{R}$ is $J$ invertible? Similarly,  if we define that map $I:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as
\begin{equation}\label{Eq4}
I(\beta)=  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^{\alpha}}\cos(\beta\ln(n))}
\end{equation}
for any $\alpha\in (0,1)$ is $I$ invertible? My thought was maybe we can invert it but not as a multivariable function and examine each piece separately.

Here are plots of $J(\alpha)$ for $\beta=3$ (left plot) and of $I(\beta)$ for $\alpha=1/2$ (right plot), as you can see these are not invertible functions.



Okay, I see it's definitely not invertible on it's domain. Maybe it's is on subdomains where the function is monotonic

You see both graphs reach maximum and minimum and perform like a wave . If we break up the function on intervals when it is monotonic it's looks like the inverse is close to $\arcsin()$
